# how to convert lists/array entries in a column to one row with different columns for each entry

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe where one column called `features` has its entries as lists of numbers over 1064 rows. So each row contains 6 to 7 columns with the `features` column where over each row it contains a list of numbers. I want to take this list, and spread it over the columns till while the number of columns is equal to `len(list)`. Here's an example:

```
print(df1[0])>>>
[-0.03980884 -0.18056028  0.11624704  0.08659928  0.02749503 -0.23401791
  0.10772136 -0.32243717 -0.09397306 -0.08458275  0.11873401  0.10531124
  0.11620065 -0.1100786  -0.27929837 -0.06915713 -0.11539902  0.26890758
 -0.16375561  0.00525901  0.01196074  0.15442082  0.10281886 -0.15471214
 -0.22901823  0.11486725 -0.05937155 -0.00580112 -0.25958595 -0.27098128
 -0.03174639 -0.20656739 -0.13286862 -0.07104845 -0.04765386 -0.08396237
  0.14032942 -0.15563552 -0.17417437  0.02441286  0.06222694 -0.08691377
  0.08214904 -0.08121296 -0.079873    0.06362587  0.06934057  0.07980402
 -0.08373277 -0.08293616 -0.07830499 -0.08762348  0.07899728 -0.04922628
 -0.02680833 -0.0853695  -0.03179847  0.00792945  0.02782207]
```

That's the first entry of the column `features` let's say I want to spread it over the dataframe in a way where it would be formatted like the following:

```
col0        col1         col2        col3       ......col59      
-0.03980884 -0.18056028  0.11624704  0.08659928 ......0.02782207
```

And most importantly I want to iterate this process over the 1064 rows.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate another dataframe which contains the values you have in the lists of the column `features` by using the last row of the following code (first three rows are used to generate data):

```
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['features']) 
df['features'] = list(np.random.random((6,3))) + list(np.random.random((6,4)))
res = pd.DataFrame(df['features'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('col')
```